# How to send image information to Popup - Ionic

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-popup

I need to open a Popup windows with an image on it. But I'm not managing to make the link between the image and the popup to work, how do I right it correctly?

Here's the code for the js popup controller:

```js
 $scope.imginstaFull = function() {
      $scope.data = {};
      $scope.imgFull = 'img/teste/insta1.jpg';
        
    
      // An elaborate, custom popup
      var myImg = $ionicPopup.show({
        template: '<ion-list style="color:black;">'+
                  '<img style="height:67vw; width:90%; border-radius:10px; 
margin:5%; background-image:url({{imgFull}});">'+   
                  '</ion-list>',                                     
        buttons: [    
          {  
            text: '<i class="icon button-icon ion-ios-close-outline"></i>',
      type:'popclose',
              
          }
        ]
      });
```

and here's the code for the html image that I want to open:

```html
<div class="col col-33 paddingPerfil colinstagram" style="background-image:url('img/teste/insta1.jpg')">             
    <button class="button button-clear button-full" ng-click="imginstaFull()"></button>       
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are using `{{imgFull}}` to reference the image inside the popup options. By sharing the original scope (using the `scope: $scope` attribute inside the `$popup.show` options, you should be able to access the `$scope.imgFull` you originally declared.
For example:

```
  $scope.imgFull = 'img/teste/insta1.jpg';
  var myImg = $popup.show({
      template: '<img style="background-image:url({{imgFull}});"></img>',
      scope: $scope,
      buttons: [  
        {  
          text: '<i class="icon button-icon ion-ios-close-outline"></i>',
          type:'popclose',

        }
      ]
   });
```

Comment: Thank you, I was reading more about it, and realized I'm using the wrong solution for what I want, I should be using Modal instead. But thank you so much for this, it may help with later solutions.